# How to detect a change in a background window

Tags: windows, window

Let's say I have a chat window open in a web browser, and I'm waiting for a message from my partner, trying to do something else in the meantime. The chat window (not an installed program) will not alert me of an incoming message, nor will the task bar flash or anything.
Is there any utility that can watch a window in the background and do something (make a sound, bring the window to front) if there is a change? 
I found AutoHotKey, using a script called livewindows.ahk, which will show a piece of the window anywhere on the screen, so I can watch the chat window, but it won't alert me on a change. I'm not skilled enough to reprogram that script, so that it would compare the contents against the initial state.
Maybe someone has invented this wheel?
Thanks in advance for any hint or advice.
Leonardo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using an instant messaging program. If so, I would find a different program. For example, Trillian does what you're asking for and connects to several major networks.

Comment: Yes, I'm using icq2go for chatting with icq contacts. I must not install IM programs on the company-owned computer, that's my problem.  I know of imo.im and meebo, but it seems you don't get that functionality in a browser thing.

Comment: just tried meebo.com, and yes it does make a sound when an icq message comes in, so I have at least a workaround.  But if soemone comes up with a solution to the original idea, I'd still be interested.